# python Django model viewset -To get current user id

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to get current user id to pass

```
class document_typeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
   group = user.group.get()
   queryset = document_type.objects.filter(role_id=group)
   serializer_class = document_typeSerializer
```

I am getting an error `AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'user'`"

Comment: you have to define a function inside class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your code:

```
class document_typeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def function_name(self, request):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        group = user.group.get()
        queryset = document_type.objects.filter(role_id=group)
        serializer_class = document_typeSerializer
```

Then you will get `request.user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need `USER` instance while `creation` (new instance creation), So you have to override `create()` as below,

```
class document_typeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = document_type.objects.filter(role_id=group)
    serializer_class = document_typeSerializer

    def get_user(self, request):
        return request.user

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # create new "document_type" instance
        current_user = request.user
        # do something with "current_user"
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Similarly, you can access the `logged-in` user whereever in your CBV, if you have a **Valid `request` object**